# BeautifulSoup Cannot Extract Metadata

Tags: python, metadata, beautifulsoup, web-scraping

I am trying to create a function which will extract meta keywords from a given URL and return it. However no matter what URLs I pass to it, it will always fail.

```
def GetKeywords(url):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
  keywords = soup.findAll('meta', attrs={'name':re.compile("^keywords$", re.I)}) #Find all meta keywords on that page
  if len(keywords) == 0: #Check to see if that page has any meta keywords to begin with
    print "No meta keywords for: " + str(url)
    return -1
  else:  #If so then return them
    return keywords
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where does the BeautifulSoup state that it would accept *and* fetch an URL?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
```

Sorry but read the BeautifulSoup documentation *first* yourself instead trying and guessing API methods..

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Parsing a Document

What you want is likely using the urllib2 module of Python for fetching data *yourself*
before feeding it into BeautifulSoup or you look at something like the scrapy module.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I literally just started learning python today, I tried reading the BS documentation but didn't quite understand it. Thanks again, much appreciated.